# Adding HTML Touch events to jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, html, touch

I am looking to add touch events to my site.  The HTML page I have built has a 6 icon display with a carousel that goes between the 14 icons (6 show, others are hidden, arrow shows the next 6)  I am trying to create an iPad version so that users can swipe across the icons to get to the next set of icons.  Looking on how to best incorporate touch events to accomplish this...looking for help getting started.

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/gVJQW/   (arrows are missing but they are directly to the left and right of the icons)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kevin

Comment: So, comment based on the first answer - I am hoping to only slightly modify my code.  I know there are ways to redo the site in all touch, but I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you only want swipe You can try something like the swipe plugin for jquery

[jQuery Swipe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/swipe)

im sure you can find more plugins depending on what you need

Answer (score 4):

http://jquerymobile.com/

Has everything you'll need to extend jquery to mobile devices including swipes and gestures... :)

Comment: I was thinking that - although I was hoping not to redo the whole site for iPad, just to add that touch event.  I will definitely be using jqtouch for the iPhone version though.